# how to initialize a string to a date-time field type in SharePoint using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating an app using visual studio in SharePoint that counts months between two dates. and I'm having problem on initializing a value. the code belongs as follows

```
DateTime _Sdate = ["Sdate"] //this one here does not work 
newDef = jobDef.Items.Add();
newDef["Sdate"] = "01/01/2015"; // i want to initialize this field to _Sdate
newDef["Ndate"] = "07/06/2015";
newDef["Cdate"] = calcDay() // I have this function in my project
```

anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you have a `SpListItem itm` which have the column named `Sdate`. Please see the below code which worked fine for me.

```
DateTime _Sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(itm["Sdate"].toString());
newDef = jobDef.Items.Add();
newDef["Sdate"] = _Sdate;
newDef["Ndate"] = "07/06/2015";
newDef["Cdate"] = calcDay(); 
newDef.Update();
```

Comment: Hey Taran thank you so much it`s working perfectly thanks so much god bless you, you saved me a lot of time!.

Comment: @NderonHyseni..that's was the reason I joined StackOverflow. Thanks for your appreciation. :)

Comment: but Taran do you have any idea what to do on this problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1007515/how-to-use-update-method-instead-of-add-in-SharePo?arn=0

Comment: you'll need to do a newTask.getItem() or use a query to fetch the desired item. You can not update something which you don't have! right?

Answer (score 4):

A DateTime cannot be a string, but you can cast it to a string using .ToString(); In order to assign a string to a datetime variable you will need to parse or convert it. You can use the Convert class to change the string to a datetime format.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx

An example would be:

```
public string aDate = "01/01/2015";
public DateTime sDate;
sDate = Convert.ToDateTime(aDate); //sDate now has a value of 01/01/2015
```

Comment: yes you are right but this in my case does not works. i need to call Sdate field anyway thanks

Comment: @NderonHyseni If it doesn't work this is a broader problem then the one you posted, I would suggest posting the full workflow.